# Magento: programmatically call "import"

Tags: php, magento, csv, import, magento-1.8

one of the manufacturers is uploading daily **.xls** files to my server, which I then use to automatically determine which products were added/removed/changed and generate **.csv import file**, which I then manually import using **System => Import / export => Import (with "replace existing complex data")**, to update products from that manufacturer.

**Problem:** I have to download .csv file and upload it using magento import functionality. I would like to schedule automatic daily import of given .csv file to Magento store.

**Tried so far:** Changing the products directly in database with SQL. This worked, but the drawbacks are: code might not work after Magento update, I can cause errors if my code doesn't update all information that should be updated, I don't get all the error checking that Magento import already has.

Is there any way to import .csv the same way as Magento does it, but to call it programatically instead of having to login to Magento and click import?

Comment: I dunno, whether you know how to create product programmatically. I hope, you knew.If so,make a new file with create products by code. Then run that file periodically by using cron.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I would not only like to add new products but also change exsisting products. If I add/change products directly, I can cause errors (if manufacturer inserted bad values in .xls), but Magento import already has all the error checking that I need, that's why I would like to achieve it this way.

Comment: Daew, In Magento Enterprise edition the same can be achieved by 'Schedule Import/Export' module. I also used the this module in Magento community (1.6) edition and it was working fine. So please seach like 'Schedule Import/Export in magento'. Hopefully you will find that module free somewhere.